# Does camel file component read the file from two different loaction?

Tags: apache-camel

Does camel file component support the below configuration?

There are two input file locations available:

E.g

1. D://input1/
2. C://input2/

Camel file component should try to read from (D://input1/) location if file available.

If file is not available in (D://input1/) location then it should read from second input file location.

Answer (score 2):

No that is not support on a single file consumer, you would have to create two routes for that. And you can then link to routes to a common/shared route using the direct component

```
from("D://input1").to("direct:shared");
from("C://input2").to("direct:shared");

from("direct:shared")"....
```